# Get Session value based on its ID

Tags: php, joomla

I am implementing SWFUpload into Joomla.
I am passing the Session ID to the server - `session_id()` - and on the server side need to retrieve `$_SESSION` value for that specific ID sent by swfupload.

My question is how to get `$_SESSION` value based on session ID?

Comment: You don't say which version of Joomla! which would help... Also, how are you trying to "implement" SWFUpload into it ? As a Joomla! extension type eg. plugin/component/module...

Comment: joomla 1.5, implementation is very customized and extensions are not ok for that.

Answer (score 4):

To set the session ID, pass it to `session_id` before calling `session_start`.

```
$sessionID = "abc123";  // or from $_POST or whatever

session_id($sessionID);
session_start();

// $_SESSION will now contain the values from the given session ID
```

Comment: I do not need to set session id, I need to get $_SESSION value based on ID.

Comment: @ihtus: Setting the session ID will make `$_SESSION` contain the values from that session ID.

Comment: let's say 2 users logged in to Joomla, so there should be 2 values of $_SESSION. I need to retrieve the values of 1st and 2nd $_SESSION not based on cookies, but based on session id

Comment: @ihtus: That's exactly what this does.  `$_SESSION` will be the session from the given ID.

Comment: I get this "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()". It's like trying to make a clone of an already existing session. The original session is there but I cannot read it based on id..

Comment: @ihtus: You need to put `session_id` *before* `session_start`.  You say you're using Joomla.  I don't know much about it, but it's probably starting a session for you (therefore a session is already started).  See if you can disable that, so that this will work.

Comment: in my php code session_id is before session_start, but I would prefer to not change joomla core files.. it seems that there is no solution.

Comment: @ihtus: Try to close Joomla's session first: `$Jsession =& JFactory::getSession(); $Jsession->close();`  **EDIT**: If you can't do that, try adding `session_write_close()` before `session_id`.

Comment: "Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user". Thank you anyway, I will use another way: will pass current user to flash, instead of session id. Thanks.

Comment: @ihtus: Sorry.  I guess the way Joomla handles sessions is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to store the relevant information somewhere other than the $_SESSION variable, since by its nature its supposed to be only available for the particular client to whom the session applies!

If you store the UserID or whatever in the DB and then use the SessionID as a key you can look up whatever info you need for your script

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I am very limited here, because Joomla uses $_SESSION, so that's why I need a solution with $_SESSION var